# VB.NET - Method argument containing Sub/Function

Tags: vb.net

Please have a look at the code below.

```
Dim results As IEnumerable(Of Customer) = ExecuteDataReader( _
               "SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE Sales> @MinSales", _
          Sub(p) p.Add("@MinSales", SqlDbType.Double).Value = 10000.0, _
          Function(r) New Customer() With {Name=r("Name"), Address=r("Address"), Sales=r("Sales") })

For Each c As Customer in results
   '...
Next
```

In a previous question I posted, the answerer posted this code. I do not understand the `sub(p)` or `function(r)` part of the code.

Unfortunately I have no basis to search for an answer to this. Therefore I have posted this question after completing a limited amount of research.

What is meant by `sub(p)` and `function(r)` ?

**Update 14:54**

Please see below.  What is meant by: `(Of T)` and `ByVal castRow As Function(Of IDataRecord, T)`?

```
Public Iterator Function ExecuteDataReader(Of T)(ByVal sql As String,
ByVal addParams as Action(Of SqlParameterCollection), ByVal castRow As
Funnction(Of IDataRecord, T)) As IEnumerable(Of T)
```

Comment: @Tim Schmelter,thanks.  I was tempted to, but the answerer has answered my original question.  This is a completely different question.  I have seen comments from other answers (not usually to my questions) where the answerer has asked for a new question.

Comment: @ Damien_The_Unbeliever, thanks.  Can you post an answer so that I can give some credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Lambda Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx):

> A lambda expression is a function or subroutine without a name that can be used wherever a delegate is valid. Lambda expressions can be functions or subroutines and can be single-line or multi-line. You can pass values from the current scope to a lambda expression.

```
Dim increment1 = Function(x) x + 1
Dim increment2 = Function(x)
                     Return x + 2
                 End Function
```

Comment: Thanks.  Why don't you have to specify the type of your parameters? In your example x could be an Integer, String, SQLConnection, Person object etc.

Comment: @w0051977 - the compiler is pretty smart - often, it can infer the types of parameters so that you don't have to supply them. Lower down on the page I've linked to "You can specify the data type of a lambda expression parameter by using the As keyword, or the data type of the parameter can be inferred. Either all parameters must have specified data types or all must be inferred."

Comment: I have updated the question.  Could you have a look at the second part? Thanks

Comment: `(Of ...)` introduces [Generic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w256ka79(v=vs.110).aspx) Type Parameters.